# requiring input before conditional statements in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

In this exercise I have a prompt where I want to require input. So if the user doesn't enter anything, it will ask again until a response is given. When a response is finally given it will go through the list of conditional statements. If a response is given on the first prompt it will simply go through that list of conditional statements. I can't seem to get this to work. What am I doing wrong here?

```js
var question =  prompt("What programming language are you currently learning?"); 
var questionUpper = question.toUpperCase();
var firstCap =  question.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + question.slice(1).toLowerCase();
while (true) {
    if (question === '') {
      var test = prompt("Please enter a programming language.");
    } else {
      break;
    } 
  if (questionUpper === 'HTML') {
      alert(questionUpper + ' is a good language to start with.');
    } else if (questionUpper === 'CSS') {
      alert(questionUpper + ' helps HTML look good.');
    } else if (firstCap === 'Javascript') {
      alert(firstCap + ' is a fun language to learn after HTML and CSS.');
    } else if (firstCap === 'Python') {
      alert(firstCap + ' is a good language, too.');
    } else  {
      alert("At least you're learning something."); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please find and use the debugger in your browser's developer tools. Step through the code. Inspect the values of the variables. You'll learn a lot more.

Comment: [console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) is also a good debugging tool.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, you should replace the `if/else if/else` sequence with `switch/case`. You could also use an object that maps from language names to messages.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is in the while cycle. You are assigning the answer to the variable "test", but the condition is checking the value of "question".

```js
var question =  prompt("What programming language are you currently learning?"); 

while (true) {
    if (question === '') {
        question = prompt("Please enter a programming language.");
    } else {
        break;
    }
}

var questionUpper = question.toUpperCase();
var firstCap =  question.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + question.slice(1).toLowerCase();

if (questionUpper === 'HTML') {
    alert(questionUpper + ' is a good language to start with.');
} else if (questionUpper === 'CSS') {
    alert(questionUpper + ' helps HTML look good.');
} else if (firstCap === 'Javascript') {
    alert(firstCap + ' is a fun language to learn after HTML and CSS.');
} else if (firstCap === 'Python') {
    alert(firstCap + ' is a good language, too.');
} else  {
    alert("At least you're learning something.");   
}
```

I also moved the upper-case after the loop in order to make it effective.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. However, I would suggest looking at other people's comments. Using the switch/case structure instead of the if/else is really better, also for readability. And remember, it's okay to ask here for hard problems, but try to understand your mistakes to learn how to correct them on your own. Debugging is always an important part of programming, and it's a nice idea to become good at it ;)

Comment: At the time, it was a hard problem. Now, I see how easy it was. I learned a lot about how to set up the code from this. Will look into using switch statements.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, you can use switch case option

```js
var question =  prompt("What programming language are you currently learning?"); 
var questionUpper = question.toUpperCase();
var firstCap =  question.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + question.slice(1).toLowerCase();

switch(questionUpper){
  case 'HTML':
    alert(questionUpper + ' is a good language to start with.');
    break;
 case 'CSS':
    alert(questionUpper + ' is a good language to start with.');
    break;
 case 'JAVASCRIPT':
    alert(questionUpper + ' is a good language to start with.');
    break;
 case 'PYTHON':
    alert(questionUpper + ' is a good language to start with.');
    break;
  default:
     alert("At least you're learning something.");  
}
```

[The sample in CodePen](https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/PQLbem)

Comment: You are not checking for empty string like @1024 wants. But good to see a `switch`, even though it won't work because you are using `questionUpper` which is all upper cases and the `case`'s have lower cases.

Comment: thanks @DanielMarques, updated my codepen and answer

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it makes much more sense to solve using a language object representation (also making it much easier to understand and edit). For example:

```
var langs = {
  html: 'HTML is a good language to start with.',
  css: 'CSS helps HTML look good.',
  javascript: 'Javascript is a fun language to learn after HTML and CSS',
  python: 'Python is a good language, too.'
}

// ask initial question
var answer =  prompt('What programming language are you currently learning?')

// ask follow up until answer is given
while(answer.length <= 0){
  answer = prompt('Please enter a programming language.')
}

// deal with answer
var lower = answer.toLowerCase()
if(langs[lower]){
  alert(langs[lower])
}else{
  alert('At least you\'re learning something.')
}
```

This way you can modify your `langs` object to contain any properties you like for each language. Maybe they have text related to other questions, or other variables you would like to associate with each language. This makes it easier to add or remove languages, or separate the data from the view, allowing you to get language data easily from a database without changing any logic.